# Quasar+vue приложение не работает на Ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu, vue.js, quasar.js

При запуске в Chromium выбрасывает ошибку `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`
Есть идеи что ему не нравится?
[image: Ошибка в браузере]

[image: Зависимости package.json]

Comment: Не нравится, что вы пользуетесь морально и технически устаревшим софтом, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal нам это тоже не нравится, но нужно именно на такой машине запустить

Comment: Ну тогда для начала попробуйте [перенастроить browserslist](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/browser-compatibility#configuring-compatibility) на нужные вам версии браузеров, но готовьтесь к боли, страданиям и посещениям психологов